# VS1053 with SMD speaker, amplifier necessary?

Tags: audio, speakers

I am working on device that looks a bit like a tablet. It consists of a display and a software controlled by touch on it. It uses the SAMA5D3 MCU from Atmel running linux.

I decided to implement audio to give the device a little bit more responsiveness and to be able to do some fancy text-to-speach stuff. I don't have space for large speakers, I found a few nice small SMD speakers around 500mW that I want to use.

I selected the well known VS1053B as the CODEC chip. VS1053 has 3 output lines, LEFT, RIGHT and GBUF.

Can I connect the SMD-Speakers (500-800mW) directely to LEFT and RIGHT, or do I have to implement an amplifier like this one: MAX98306?

How to connect the speakers? One speakers + to LEFT, the other speakers + to RIGHT and both speakers - to GBUF?

If I just want to use one speaker, can I connect LEFT to RIGHT?

Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](http://www.vlsi.fi/fileadmin/datasheets/vs1053.pdf) says it has a "standard 30 ohm headphone driver", so if you want to drive speakers you'll need an amplifier.